# application open on startup in background

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, startup

Apologies if this question has already been asked.
I currently have it in the startup folder, but I'm not sure what code to use to not open the parent form.
I want my vb.net application to open on startup but in the background so it doesn't annoy users when they log in.
How would i go about setting that up?

Comment: If you app is hidden from the start how can the user see it later on? Is there something in the notification bar? think about that. I would suggest going with @FloatingKiwi answer. But as well I will add a check for the program arguments and say if the argument "hidden" is exist then and only then I will start the app in hidden mode (then in the startup folder you put a shortcut with the "hidden" argument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent a form from showing itself (but still create itself) you can override the following code in the form.

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(value As Boolean)
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(False)
End Sub
```

This will always hide your form. Obviously pass true to make it display on whatever criteria you'd like to use.

This approach doesn't require you to restructure your application to separate ui + logic.

Comment: Thanks @FloatingKiwi this the sort of answer i was looking for. Another quick question, using this sub hides the form even when trying to open it from its desktop shortcut. Do you know any code that will allow me to open the form from that shortcut? If you can answer this is will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: I'd do it using a command line parameter. In your startup shortcut use /hideui. Then your application can check the value of `Command()` and decide what to pass to `MyBase.SetCoreVisible`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all the form init code to a  `sub Main` function in a new module a set that function as a start up function, after the init code add:

```
dim frm as new <your_form>
```

after when you want to display it only call `frm.show` or `frm.showdialog`

Comment: This is not correct. The form's `Load` event will not be raised just because you instantiate a new instance. It is raised the first time the form is about to be shown by the `SetVisibleCore()` method (which is executed when you call for example `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`).